# Convert active speaker level to microphone level

Tags: resistors

I would like to make a cable for recording from xlr lineoutput (active speaker with mixer) to Android phone.

What impedence should be used?
What would be pinout from xlr to trrs 3,5 on phone?

I can work with soldering iron :)

Thank you.

Comment: Is the output signal balanced or unbalanced?

Comment: here is the only info about OUTPUT from EV Everse8 speaker manual: IX OUT - XLR output sends either the mix of all input signals or the stereo L or stereo R
signal to another loudspeaker or subwoofer

Answer (score 0):

Line output is typically 0dBm which equates to 775mV RMS into a 600R load.  Microphone outputs are typically somewhat less than this, around 100mV.  The phone will provide a DC voltage, typically a couple of bolts and you may need to load this with a resistance (often 1 to 2k) for the phone to activate the microphone input.  For a crude-but-effective solution you could use a resistor divider to reduce the voltage (with XLR live and return as mic and ground to the phone) but a better solution would be to use a 600R isolating transformer coupled capacitively to a resistive divider.

Comment: Sure, line output could be what you say, but you don't say under which conditions. That's the problem. When you say 775mVrms, when exactly it is that? There might even be no answer to that. For reference, modern DACs have 2Vrms output, at full scale digital signal, volume controls set to unity.

Comment: @Justme that is one of the ongoing problems for audio, 0dBm is a nominal value, while real-world sound levels cover many orders of magnitude.  You’d hope that a phone mic input has fairly effective compression and/or AGC plus many bits of ADC precision so it can be quite forgiving.

Comment: Yes but in a broadcast or recording studio they would at least define what it means to use a nominal level and what are the allowed maximum value when using that nominal level. And 0 dBm is not a valid unit because the power is not 1mW unless the load is 600R and 600R impedance hasn't been used in decades. So that's why a matching voltage level is used for any impedance and it's 0 dBu. Generally 0 dBu in analog world is -18 or -20 dBFS level in digital world, so you can have peaks 8x or 10x higher than "nominal".

Comment: Guys, your discussion becomes a rocket science for me :). Is it possible to provide a schema for newbie. So all what I have to do is make a soldering (cable, connectors, resistors. Capacitor? :) ). Thank you.

Comment: I’m on my phone and away from home so can’t easily do that until tomorrow unless @Justme would care to field it?

Comment: no rush at all. Thank you!